# Web fonts look choppy in Firefox only

Tags: html, css, firefox, font-face

- OS: Win 7 64bit
- Browser: FF 24.0

If I go to http://www.google.com/fonts it looks awful:

[image: Firefox font issue]

And when I load one for my site locally it looks equally as bad but here is my configuration that I generated from fontsquirrel below:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'SecretSans';
        src: url('<%=domain_url%>/fonts/secretsansextralight-webfont.eot');
        src: url('<%=domain_url%>/fonts/secretsansextralight-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('<%=domain_url%>/fonts/secretsansextralight-webfont.svg#secretsansttextralight') format('svg'),
             url('<%=domain_url%>/fonts/secretsansextralight-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('<%=domain_url%>/fonts/secretsansextralight-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

Because it looks just as bad on the site above and my own site I presume it's an issue with Firefox and/or Windows.

Is there a fix/configuration that will work for all users hitting my site that doesn't require them changing any settings within Firefox or Windows as that's obviously unrealistic.

EDIT1: I just went to Control Panel > Fonts > Adjust ClearType text and now it renders properly in Firefox... I can't ask users to do this though so I'm hoping there is another way

Comment: Strange, the text renders fine for me when I view the link, using firefox. Maybe try a re-instal? Have any other machines you can test on?

Comment: Can you check Control Panel > Fonts > Adjust ClearType text and see if it's turned on. I suspect it is which is why it looks good for you.

Comment: It is indeed turned on

Comment: Installing (Service Pack 1) helped in my case (Windows 7 - 64 bit).

Comment: if you don't hate your visitors, use Arial, it works well on both cleartype and non cleartype. Most fonts are designed to only work well on cleartype enabled, and give eye cancer otherwise. Since Windows XP+, there's a bug that makes all fonts cleartype whether you want to or not unless you disable cleartype altogether via registry and cleartype tuner. To add salt to the wound, there is no easy way of checking whether clients accessing your content have cleartype or not, and guessing wrong means they will get a poor impression of your content

Answer (score 5):

I know this thread is from the stoneage, but unfortunately the problem is still current. And if you google for the choppy fonts problem, it's in the top 10; so I want to add my 10 Cents of experience with it!

Ok: If you search Google for problem with fonts under Vista/Win 7/Win 8, you find two major groups of problems that are both related to ClearType in many cases. Not all! But many.

---

Group 1: Blurry Windows fonts

If we talk of "Windows fonts" we are talking of the user interface (menus and such), and the "workspace" of office apps like Word or Excel.
This problem hits almost all people that do **not** have a 16:9 widescreen monitor that is HD capable, esp. classic office-type monitors of 19" and 1280x1024 resolution. The keyword is "Low-DPI" here.

For those who don't know: ClearType does a HORRIBLE job on these Low-DPI monitors and renders the whole interface in such a blurry way that trying to work with it causes massive eye strain and headache. Really folks, it gives you eye cancer! 
(and no, you can not recreate that prob' on a Full-HD monitor!)

The only way out is to disable ClearType. This helped almost everybody of group 1 - including me.

---

Group 2: Choppy font rendering in Firefox and Chrome (rarely MSIE)

In many, many cases - like in this thread - ClearType was disabled. And when re-enabled, the browsers do render fonts just fine. True for me, too!

---

Unfortunately... when I re-enable ClearType, I'm back in group 1!!!

So: EITHER I have ClearType disabled and can work with a sharp and clear Windows for hours without fatigue of my eyes - but then I have to live with choppy webfonts in FF and Chrome.

OR I re-enable ClearType to see the nice and nifty fonts the designers have chosen for their oh-so-stylish websites - and live with the headache Windows gives me due to the blurry fonts! :-(

Obviously, I'm going the first way. 
And if I stumble about a website where fonts look like broken, I simply toggle the usage of webfonts with just one mouse click - there's a great FF-AddOn for that.

Oh, I forgot: Why seems MSIE to render the fonts nicely?

Well, IE (at least 10 and 11 to my knowledge) always uses ClearType to render a page - no matter if disabled in the system settings or not. 
Of course, it then also shows the blurry fonts problem - and makes me remember why I have ClearType disabled. And will let it so!

Final thoughts:
Programmers believe webfonts to be the final solution to all of their design-needs, thinking, they have everything under control by testing their stuff on a couple of default systems. In fact, webfonts just made a well-known problem freak out of any control - because there is no such thing like a default user!

Think about it.

Comment: Unfortunate that this solution doesn't work for everyone, but after having this issue on various computers, for the past few years, I realized I'm in "Group 2", and this immediately fixed the issue (choppy font rendering was only on Firefox for me). And now I feel like like a dope for not realizing ClearType was off. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it is just how the browser renders it.  Especially with @font-face stuff (I am assuming you used http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ or a similar site to generate it).  You can use a little bit of text shadow to make it a little bit crisper, but from what you have shown, I think you might be better off trying to find another very similar font that will render better.

Comment: I had a coworker test with an old version of FF(13) and it actually renders properly for him. This made me think there might be a way to fix it for later versions of FF somehow. I'll most likely have to not use custom fonts because of this but if I can easily avoid it with some sort of config that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

This was obviously because you had ClearType switched off. It's the method used to smooth the edges of fonts on computer screens (LCD). It has nothing to do with the method used in the webpage to attach them, this is strictly a font rendering issue. Fonts may appear differently depending on the system, as each has a slightly different method of rendering them - they tend to look best on Apple systems, while Windows seems to have a somehow inferior rendering method. This is entirely up to the system that is running, so the fonts will render differently for various users. Also, professional fonts from big foundries generally render much, much better than free, open fonts, because they're specifically corrected to optimize how they're rendered on screen, especially when they're rendered small (below 20px size), so the roughness of fonts from the Google Fonts set might also in part be due to the fact they're not as carefully crafted as those professional, expensive ones. Nevertheless, regardless of the font quality, text will always look uglier and choppy if font smoothing is switched off (or not supported), so there is nothing you can do. Stopping yourself from using custom webfonts because you're worried about the fraction of users who have font smoothing turned off is will stop you from using them at all.