# Why do Google fonts look so much crisper in Chrome than IE/FireFox?

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, fonts

I can't work out why my Google fonts in an app I'm developing look so much crisper and cleaner in Chrome than they do in Internet Explorer and FireFox.  The difference in the body text isn't so dramatic, but it's particularly noticeable in the heading elements (see examples below).

What's even stanger is that the font rendering in Chrome differs between my app and when using the Google Fonts Typecast tool.  The rendering in Typecast looks more like the rendering in IE/FireFox than it does in my app (see examples below).

I'm using the Open Sans Google Font with the following CSS reference:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I'm also using Bootstrap for my app - not sure if that is relevant but it's the only other thing I can think of that could make a difference.

Google Chrome font rendering (headings look crisp and smooth):

[image: Google Chrome font rendering]

Internet Explorer font rendering (headings look almost pixelated and squarish):

[image: Internet Explorer font rendering]

Font rendering in Typecast using Chrome (headings look the same as they do in IE)

[image]

Any idea why these fonts are rendering so differently?

**UPDATE**

I downloaded a showcase solution from Typecast and was getting the same results running the demo locally on my machine, in that the fonts were looking un-crisp, but ultra crisp in my app (both in Chrome).  So I created a clean .html file with just a `h2` heading and a paragraph and added the Google font CSS reference.  Ultra crisp.  So I started testing on the Typecast show case app which includes the semi bold 600, bold 700 and extra bold 800 fonts.  If I remove these fonts and just use the normal 400 the fonts render as crisp and as expected.  So that at least explains why I was getting different result in Chrome. But, still I don't understand why other browsers don't render the fonts just as crisply.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279461/web-fonts-look-choppy-in-firefox-only

Comment: @epascarello Apologies, but I don't see how that explains the difference between why the fonts look so crips in my app and so un-crisp in Typecast  - both using Chrome.  And the fonts are not "choppy" - they're just not AS crisp as they are in my app, which makes me think this is unrelated to the ClearType issue.

Comment: It was a suggestion, not an answer. Did you look to see if ClearType was set on the other browsers?

Comment: I thought ClearType was a system wide setting, i.e., not browser specific?